# How do I print a local tensor in tensorflow?

Tags: python, debugging, variables, tensorflow, local

I want to print a tensor in my program to see its internal values once it gets evaluated. The problem, however, is that the tensor being declared inside a function. To understand my problem better, here is some example code to better explain what it is I want to do:

```
a = tf.Variable([[2,3,4], [5,6,7]])
b = tf.Variable([[1,2,2], [3,3,3]])

def divide(a,b):
    with tf.variable_scope('tfdiv', reuse=True):
        c = tf.divide(a,b, name='c')
    # Cannot print(c) here, as this will only yield tf info on c
    return c

d = divide(a,b)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    sess.run(d)
    sess.run(tf.get_variable('tfdiv/c:0').eval(session=sess))
```

Previously, I have been able to do a print(c.eval(session=sess)), but as c is a local variable inside a function now, that does not work. As can be seen in the code above, I have tried to use tensorflow's variable scope in order to access the variable and then evaluate it. Unfortunately, this results in the error message:

```
ValueError: Shape of a new variable (tfdiv/c:0) must be fully defined, but 
instead was <unknown>.
```

I tried to use the reuse=True flag, but I still get the same error. Any thoughts on how I can solve this problem? Best would be if there is a print(c) equivalent that can be put into the divide function, as written in the code above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will achieve what you want to do:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print(sess.run(d))
```

Alternatively, you could replace the last line with:

```
print(sess.run(tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name('tfdiv/c:0')))
```

Comment: Your second solution is the one I was looking for, as this also works when the function gets more tf variables to it. I take it there is no way to put a print statement within the function?

Answer (score 1):

It is important to understand the difference between Python side code and TensorFlow side code. In python, you only setup the graph:    `d = divide(a, b)` creates something like:
[image]

You set up a *node* (square) that will divide the data in the *nodes* `a` and `b`. It doesn't divide them right away! Note that in black you have the *python* variable names, and in gray you have the *TensorFlow* node names <sup>1</sup>. `a` and `b` also have some default names, if you didn't specify them. The gray "c" you specified with `name='c'`. And local variable `c` and global variable `d` (Python) both refer to that same operation (node).

This is why if you say `print(d)` merely prints the info about that node. Once you setup the graph, doing `sess.run(d)` runs all the nodes required by the node in `d` *on TensorFlow side*. Then it retrieves the result and makes it available *on python side* as a numpy array.

You can use [`tf.Print(input, data)`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Print) to print tensors *on TF side*. Note this is an operation (a node in the graph) that does nothing to the `input` tensor, it merely passes it through, while also printing everything in `data`.

In your case, you can use `Print` on tensorflow side it like this:

```
def divide(a,b):
    with tf.variable_scope('tfdiv', reuse=True):
        c = tf.divide(a,b, name='c')
        cp = tf.Print(c, [c], message='Value of c: ', name='P')

    return cp
```

This effectively adds another node in the graph (named `P` on TF side):

[image: Graph of tensors illustrating the above]

Now the value of *operation* `c` will be printed every time it will be evaluated. Note it will also be printed every time one of its dependencies will be evaluated, for example if you later do `e = d + 1`, when you evaluate `e`, it needs `d`, which refers to the printing node (returned from the function `divide`).

Finally, note that if you do this in a Jupyter notebook, the print will appear in the terminal of the notebook server. The details of this are not important for now :).

<sup>1</sup> the `:0` is added by default so that you can retrieve any tensor with by using `name_of_op:0`. Distinction between name of operation (`tfdiv/c`) and name of tensor(`tfdiv/c:0`).

Comment: Hi, Ciprian. Can we save the tensor values in txt or binary files based on this method?

Comment: there may be some way by overriding the tensorflow logger, but I don't know them personally. If you need more serious debugging, try looking into `tfdbg` https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/debugger